# How should I sign myself on poster if I am a student?

Tags: publications, poster

I am preparing a scientific poster for a conference. Most researchers' posters have on the top of page header:

```
TITLE
FIRST+LAST
INSTITUTION
```

I am currently a bachelor student and this work is being created independently from my university. Should I write

```
TITLE
FIRST+LAST
UNIVERSITY NAME
```

or just

```
TITLE
FIRST+LAST
```

Comment: Will anyone being paying your fees? Is the data through the university?

Comment: No, data is generated. It is computer science problem. Universities are free in Poland (paid from taxes)

Comment: You are doing all the work on your own hardware, without input from anyone at the university? And not university fees, conference fees

Comment: Part of computation is done on private hardware, rest on colab.research.google.com. To be more specific (I don't included that in question because it doesn't matter) I co-work with my friend, also from the same university. Also university won't pay for conference fees.

Comment: Then I think it would be appropriate to list yourself without the uni

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that any of them would be fine. Instead of an institution, it is also acceptable to describe yourself as "Independent Researcher" or the equivalent, depending on the venue. But listing the university could be taken as identification only.

There is an exception, of course. If you are doing something that the university would object to for some reason, then it is better not to name them unless you clarify, somehow, that you aren't suggesting they authorize or subscribe to what you have done. But even then, "Student at Moo U." is an accurate portrayal.